# How to give a user only select permission on a database

Tags: sql-server, database, permissions

I want a to create a new user on a db with only the select permissions (read only access)
how can i do this ?
i'm working with sql 2008

Comment: Hiya - this is the kind of question that ServerFault.com was designed for, since it's more of an administration question as opposed to a programming question. You might have better luck there (and this question might get migrated there from here). Welcome to StackOverflow, though. :)

Answer (score 55):

You could add the user to the Database Level Role **db_datareader**.

Members of the db_datareader fixed database role can run a SELECT statement against any table or view in the database.

See Books Online for reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121%28SQL.90%29.aspx

You can add a database user to a database role using the following query:

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'userName'
```

Answer (score 27):

You can use Create USer to create a user

```
CREATE LOGIN sam
    WITH PASSWORD = '340$Uuxwp7Mcxo7Khy';
USE AdventureWorks;
CREATE USER sam FOR LOGIN sam;
GO
```

and to Grant (Read-only access) you can use the following

```
GRANT SELECT TO sam
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 20):

For the GUI minded people, you can:

- Right click the Database in Management Studio.
- Choose Properties
- Select Permissions
- If your user does not show up in the list, choose Search and type their name
- Select the user in the Users or Roles list
- In the lower window frame, Check the Select permission under the Grant column

Answer (score -2):

```
create LOGIN guest WITH PASSWORD='guest@123', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
```

Be sure when you want to exceute the following

```
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO guest;

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::BiddingSystemDB TO guest
```

Selected Database should be Master